# Can't search Gmail

Tags: lumia, email, 7.8, gmail

When I search for email on my phone (Lumia 800, WP 7.8), it has no results, even when I choose "search more in Google Mail" (which I assume searches mail on the server which hasn't been downloaded to the phone.
It says no results, search all folders which also yields no results.

However when I go to my contacts/(name of contact)/history/more/search Google Mail, it shows me email from that person, so I know some form of search is working.

How can I search for mail from that person via the mail app instead of having to go via contacts history? Eg if I want to search for email that isn't from any contact eg a flight booking.